# After Magento server move I get SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: magento-1.9

Please can someone help, I am tearing out what little hair I have left.

I had to move a clients Magento from one 1and1 server to another and I am getting the above error message when trying to access the site. Whilst 1and1 server support has tried to be helpful their Magento knowledge is limited and I am not getting very far.

Initially I was told to just upload the Magento files and database onto the new server after which I was getting the above error report. After three days of trying to get help at 1and1 someone said that I should have installed Magento first through Plesk and then uploaded the files. I duly did this and prior to uploading the original files Magento was actually working with the basic installation page and I could get access to Admin but after uploading the files and the database I am back to the square one.

I have checked over and over again the local.xml with the settings in Plesk and as far as I can see the database settings are correct.

The database can be seen in ssh command line. I have restarted the server.

Comment: Can you send the full error message from domain's error log? Should be located in Plesk > Domains > your_domain_name > Logs. Click Start real-time updates and open the site in a browser in order to generate some new logs.

Generally there should be a file where you specify connection settings, like /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/system/library/db/mysqli.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Got it sorted. I had renamed the original local.xml file to loacalold.xml and didn't realise that Magento reads all the xml files in the app/etc folder. Deleted that file and all was OK

Answer (score 0):

In your env.php under the 'db' section, the value of the host,dbname, username, and password should be set properly. If your facing this issue at your local with the host then set 'host' => 'localhost', or 'host' => '127.0.0.1'